# Get records having SUM(val) same AS MAX(SUM(val))

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, max

There's my SQL:

```
SELECT prefs.* 
FROM form_answer fa 
JOIN game g ON g.id = fa.game_id
JOIN customer c ON c.code = fa.`data`
JOIN (
    SELECT c.code code, p.pnt_version_id ver, prod_type, ROUND(SUM(value)/40*100,1) AS val
    FROM point p JOIN customer c
    GROUP BY c.code, p.pnt_version_id, prod_type
    ORDER BY val DESC   
) prefs ON g.pnt_version_id = prefs.ver AND c.code = prefs.code

WHERE fa.game_id = 44 AND fa.question_id = 34
ORDER BY prefs.val DESC
```

```
+------+-----+-----------+------+
| code | ver | prod_type | val  |
+------+-----+-----------+------+
|  101 | 110 |         1 | 87.5 |
|  101 | 110 |         3 | 87.5 |
|  101 | 110 |         2 | 62.5 |
+------+-----+-----------+------+
```

Now I need to get only those records with same val AS MAX(val). Any help, please?